# Send Email via C# through my LAN interface

Tags: c#, .net, email

I am trying to simulate some ad hoc network, I use my wireless card to connect to the ad hoc network, I want to be able to mail myself some specific messages when I get some trigger from this ad hoc network. my laptop connected to internet via Lan interface and connect to ad hoc network via wireless card.

this id my code:

```
 private void send_mail()
        {
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            message.To.Add("XXXXX@YYYY.com");
            message.Subject = "test";
            message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("ZZZZZ@MMMMM.com");
            message.Body = "This is the message body";
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("a.b.c.d");
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
```

I want to know How can I set interface for sending mail.
by default the code want use my wireless card to send mail and can't connect to smtp server and I got error.
I want my send_mail() function connect through LAN interface not wireless interface.

Comment: This should work automatically if "a.b.c.d" is in the network of the LAN and not of the adhoc network.  The PC would know to send traffic to the appropriate interface.  Have you tried it and it is not working?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: @rerun I want to be able to select specific interface for connecting to smtp server, in this code I want my send_mail() function connect through LAN interface.

Answer (score 1):

It's an IP routing problem. You need to setup routes on your computer to direct access to a.b.c.d through the WiFi interface.

Open a command prompt with Admin privileges and use the `route add` command.

Comment: my WiFi interface can just connect to my ad hoc network which didn't access to internet, I connect to internet via my LAN Card.

Answer (score 1):

Set your LAN interface to be your default gateway, or set your LAN interface to be your default connection/internet connection.

The operating system has to know to use the LAN interface first for internet connections.

Answer (score 0):

one option that comes to mind is to block port 25 on the port you dont want to send though... Is the Ad-Hoc network connected to an Internet Connection? if not, the email should go though your Wired Network connection anyway....

Answer (score 0):

That's outside of the scope of the `SmtpClient` it's pretty much as if you try to resolv an adress using the command promt and do a `ping` or `lookup`, it will use the interface that can reach that address.

Also, be sure that the relay you are using is using port 25. You can try telnet to it first, if that works you should be able to connect to it using `SmtpClient`.

Comment: I think you didn't get my problem or I didn't get your answer.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA, If I understand you correct, you want to select what network interface to use with your `SmtpClient`, but that is not possible, the operating system will detect on what interface what network addresses is available. If you are having problem connecting to the Smtp Server you should first of all verify that it works using `telnet`.

Comment: No I have not problem to connect to smtp server, I can telnet to it. my problem is that I can't connect to smtp server via my code. I have 2 interface I=on my laptop, one interface for connect to ad hoc network other interface for connecting to internet but I don't know How tell C# choose lan interface for connecting to smtp server (by default it user my WiFi interface)

Comment: There is no way to do that. You should ask on Superuser

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to choose the network card to use.
From within .NET you cannot choose which network card is used to open a socket for network communication.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an issue with how the network is set up on your PC, so it might be worth asking about that on superuser.com.

However, if nothing else works, you could temporarily disable your wireless connection before sending the email and then enable it again afterwards. Assuming that you're using DHCP, you can do this via WMI, the top sample on this page shows how you [can disable a network connection using WMI?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa394595). If you're not using DHCP there's still ways of doing this but it's a bit more difficult.

If you haven't used WMI in C# before, this article might be a good starting point: [WMI Made Easy For C#](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/10/wmi-made-easy-for-c/)

Or taking Serge's answer as a starting point, you can do `Route add` programmatically via [CreateIpForwardEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365860%28VS.85%29.aspx) and later delete it via [DeleteIpForwardEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365878%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: the WMI first sample code "disable a network connection "? how it understand which connection must be disable?(my ad hoc or my lan)? then Hoe can I enable it again? both of my interface connect to their network via DHCP.